# Deletion of an element from a linear list

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, logic

I'm brushing up on my **Data structures and algorithms** and I just ran into a problem with deletion from linear lists.I need help with mostly the logic so that I can comfortably implement code in any language. However, I'm learning C and C++ currently and would appreciate if any code was written in the same.

Given the list below, my aim is to delete the element **c**.
[image: OldList]

After deletion, the new list should look like this:
[image]

Now notice, I did the following in order to come up with the new list:

1) Searched for c

2)Deleted c

3)Shifted the other elements to the left because:

**By definition:** Linear lists should be sequential. One element comes after the other  and there should be no "gaps"

I understand the logic for doing the search and shifting and can comfortably implement them in code. Now my problem is with the logic for deletion. That's where I need help.

I am implementing my linear lists using arrays **(Not sure if there's any other way)**.Reducing the size of the array is **not** an option. I need the size of the array to remain the same... 5 in this case

**Summary:** How do you delete an element from a linear list?

Comment: "No other way than an array?" It can be done with a linked list.

Comment: You could also implement an array-backed list, which has both a practical size (the length of the array) and a logical size (the number of elements).

Comment: How are you currently tracking the size of the array? Decrease that by one when you erase an element. If you're tracking the array by using `sizeof`, then stop doing that, and encase your `data` in a class with your `size`, and add some methods for common operations.

Comment: Ye-ep. C and C++ are designed around very different ideologies and target different niches. That's not to say that they can't be used in the other's niches, just that the other is "better" at it. Learn them both, but know, appreciate, and take advantage of the differences.

Comment: I don't really see the problem here. Unless you're asking how to know that the array, which is allocated to hold 5 items, only holds 4 relevant items after deletion. The answer to that question is that you either keep a counter that tells you how many relevant items, or you mark the "empty" slots with a sentinel value.

Comment: By the way, another way to remove an item from the list is to just take the item that's at the end, and place it in the position of the item you want to remove. That has the advantage of being much faster than shifting all the items to the left, but the disadvantage of changing the order. Not a problem when order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is an **ArrayList**. They maintain an integer-variable often called `size` that says how much of the array is currently used. In your case, after the deletion the last slot of the array is empty, thus `size` would be 4, even though the length of the array is still 5.

The pseudocode for the algorithm for deletion would be (with array indices starting at 0 and the array called `arr`) :

```
pos <- index of element you want to delete
from i <- pos to size-1:
    arr[i] = arr[i+1]
size <- size-1
```

What this does is the same as you did in your question: Find the element, and delete it by replacing its value by the one that follows and also do this for all following values. At the end safe, that the list is now 1 smaller.

Comment: if there is a resource on how to write pseudocode on stackoverflow, please point me to it